# htaccess - One clean URL working but not the other

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls, pretty-urls

htaccess files have never been a strong point for me unfortunately.

I'll just jump right in:

```
#Turn RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


#Canonicalize URL
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain-removed\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.domain-removed.com/$1 [L,R,NE]


#Add Trailing Slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
    RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]


#Clean URLs
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^themes/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ themes/view.php?theme=$1
    RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ account/index.php?page=$1
```

So going to `domain.com/themes/theme-name/` and `domain.com/themes/view.php?theme=theme-name` works fine and both show the same page/results. However, going to `domain.com/account/index.php?page=page` works but going to `domain.com/account/page/` doesn't, it just returns a 404 Not Found.

`page` variables can be things such as `login`, `create`, `dashboard` and `logout` etc. The `index.php` in the account directory will process this variable.

It's confusing me as to why it doesn't work as it's the same situation, just under a different directory and a different file name, but both are declared in the rule. Anyone now what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've also tried doing this and defining the pages, like so:

```
    RewriteRule ^account/login/$ account/login.php
    RewriteRule ^account/logout/$ account/logout.php
    RewriteRule ^account/create/$ account/create.php
    RewriteRule ^account/dashboard/$ account/dashboard.php
```

But still it just returns a 404

Comment: Does `/account/index.php` exist at `www.domain-removed.com`?

Answer (score 2):

Replace account with themes directory in your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ themes/view.php?theme=$1
```

If this works check if there's any other `.htaccess` under the account directory interfering here. If you're unable to find any other file also check for any conflicting RewriteRule(s) in `httpd.conf` (under `<Directory>` tags).

If nothing gives, mark your rule as `[L]`ast i.e. `mod_rewrite` should stop processing it any more.

```
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ account/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried it out locally and couldn't reproduce it. The account works fine.

- I had problems with your redirect to domain-removed.com. Are your sure you want to redirect all requests to this domain?.
- follow **Ravi Thapliyal**'s answer.

The other points are obvious:

- Please make sure you spell the name of your fold 'account' and the index.php correctly
- When trying `RewriteRule ^account/login/$ account/login.php` make sure login.php exists.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you aren't matching action-page because of the hypen, adding a hyphen as part of the character set being matched will resolve this

```
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ account/index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Apologies, that was my mistake, `action-page` just referred to a page such as `login` or `create`, I completely forgot to mention! I'll edit now!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[L,PT]` to the `RewriteRule` directives.

```
RewriteRule ^themes/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ themes/view.php?theme=$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ account/index.php?page=$1 [L,PT]
```

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Answer (score 0):

I can see few mistakes in your .htaccess like:

1. Using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` only for `themes` rule but skipping `account` rule.
2. Not ending Rewrite rules with `L` (Last) flag.
3. Not using QSA (Query String Append) flag to preserve the query string.

Here is your modified .htaccess that you should try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force www.domain-removed.com domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain-removed\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-removed.com/$1 [L,R=302,NE]

# add trailing slash
RewriteRule (?!^(?:.*?/|.+?\..*)$)^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]

## Clean URLs  

# do nothing for real files, directories or sym-links
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule - [L]

# no handle /themes/ and /account/ URIs
RewriteRule ^themes/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /themes/view.php?theme=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /account/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: QSA is not required since OP is matching on directories without any query string. Likewise, the "!-d" condition when not in effect shouldn't affect redirection. But, yes it's a good catch and OP should fix it once the issue is resolved.